# Javamail Could not convert socket to TLS GMail

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using JavaMail through Gmail SMTP Server. This is the code:

```
final String username = "mygmail@gmail.com";
final String password = "mygmailpassword";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
);

try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("test@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
    message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Done");
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Returns an this error:

> Could not convert socket to TLS;

The complete stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at Test.main(Test.java:43)
> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
> at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
> at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
> at Test.main(Test.java:38)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
> at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
> at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:486)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1902)
> ... 7 more
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
> at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
> at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
> ... 17 more
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
> at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
> at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
> ... 23 more

Comment: please give the complete stack trace. Your exact code runs fine on my machine

Comment: @Laabidi I already posted it.

Answer (score 162):

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

Comment: Can you expand on why/how you think this proposed solution will resolve the question?

Comment: This one did the magic but the answer could do better at expanding on a bit of more details like @Denomales says. Good tip though. My guess is that this prop tells you programme to blindly trust ssl connection whether it has the right certificate ?

Comment: From javamail docs - `mail.smtp.ssl.trust` If set, and a socket factory hasn't been specified, enables use of a MailSSLSocketFactory. If set to "*", all hosts are trusted. If set to a whitespace separated list of hosts, those hosts are trusted. Otherwise, trust depends on the certificate the server presents.

Comment: For me `props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");` did the trick

Comment: This is not a good thing to do unless you really know what you're doing and why.  This opens yourself up to MITM attacks.  Now, you would have to be pretty stupid to mess this up, but I look back to the Lenovo certificate issue to inform us of how this can be so brutally dangerous unless you're absolutely sure you can trust the server and all the paths to the server.
A better way to resolve this is to actually find out why the certificate isn't being accepted.  Likely because you need a CA like letsencrypt.

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: @Bluebaron are you talking to Burak or @carlos?

Comment: @AryaPourtabatabaie carlos

Comment: @Bluebaron So should he have put a higher up CA as trusted instead of Gmail directly?

Comment: @AryaPourtabatabaie, no. He should rely on the operating system to automatically sort that out.  It's likely, actually probable, that he has a configuration issue.  He's circumventing the protections put in place.

Comment: working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: This only worked if you also remove any mention of mail.smtp.socketFactory . This is apparently not even needed anymore.  Trusting only worked when I did that.

Comment: Downvoted, because trusting a host blindly can create Man-In-The-Middle Attacks. You should check other options to make sure the SSL cert can be verified.

Comment: @trilogy, MITM can present itself as the trusted host with a self-signed certificate with that host name. You need to verify the certificate's signature with the root (CA) certificate. However I'm stuck here, as I haven't seen an example how to add a custom truststore. Jakarta mail uses the default java truststore, but since I'm connecting to an somewhat exotic server I need to add an outside truststore. I'm still looking for an example. I didn't find the jakarta mail manual very helpfull.

Answer (score 44):

I disabled avast antivirus for 10 minutes and get it working.

Answer (score 39):

Make sure your antivirus program isn't interfering and be sure to add an exclusion to your firewall.

Comment: am a victim of this question, what i gave is my own solution,

Comment: Truly said. Avast was creating problem. Thanx buddy

Comment: Same here, Avast was somehow the problem

Comment: AVG version 18.1.3044 (with Windows 10) interfer with my Spring application. Solution: enter in AVG section called "Web and email" and disable the "email protection".

Comment: Avast was my problem as well. Deactivated it for 10 minutes and everything worked.

Comment: in my case when i turned off Avast it worked

Answer (score 38):

I got similar problem when default SSL protocol for sending emails was set to TLSv1 and smtp server was not supporting this protocol anymore.
Trick was to use newer protocol:

mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2

Answer (score 14):

The first answer from **@carlos** worked for me:

```
session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

I have tested the property below and worked perfectly for me too:

```
session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

The two properties alone solved this type of problem, but by guarantee I used both.

Answer (score 13):

After a full day of search, I disabled Avast for 10 minutes and Windows Firewall (important) and everything started working!

This was my error:

```
Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**Here is how to fix the issue in Avast 19.8.2393** by adding an exclusion to SMTP port 587 (or whichever port your application uses):

1. Open Avast
2. Click on 'Settings'
3. Click on 'Troubleshooting' and then 'Open old settings'

[image]

4. Click again on 'Troubleshooting', scroll down to 'Redirect settings' and delete the port that your app uses.

[image]

In my case, I just removed 587 from SMTP ports.

Now I am able to use Avast and also have my Windows Firewall switched on (no need to add additional exclusion for the Firewall).

Here are my **application.properties** e-mail properties:

```
###### I am using a Google App Password which I generated in my Gmail Security settings ######
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.protocol = smtp
spring.mail.username = gmail account
spring.mail.password = password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Comment: In my case it was the same but different antivirus. Thanks, It helped a lot

Comment: Thanks, for me it was the antivirus too, before testing the change I disabled the antivirus for an hour, to do the tests, after deactivating the antivirus the emails were executed without any problem.

Answer (score 10):

check that you have all this fields

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: Seems, going ahead aws ses is supported only "TLSv1.2+"

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was solved by **deleting** the line

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

It may be because of some ssl configuration errors on email server, I'm not sure. Email server administrators never admit it and always blame hosting provider :)

Comment: Commenting the Jave line of code "htmlEmail.setStartTLSEnabled(true);" (org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail) also solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

above application.properties worked amazing for me:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: when using spring - plain javamail properties can be found here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#properties

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the "Nested Exception".  If the nested exception is "no appropriate protocol" then specify the protocol in a System property:

```
-Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

I see that some people suggest to set it in the code that creates the STMP session, but that would require a patching and deployment if you want to update the value in the future.  Using a System property allows you to update it without changing the code.

Comment: This was the solution for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can also be if the application does not support the *TLS version* the SMTP host is using.

For example, trying to configure an SMTP server that uses TLSv1.2 without fallback, when your application(or java program using an older javax.mail JAR) supports only upto TLSv1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the port to 465

```
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.port=465
```

Answer (score 2):

Below set of properties in `application.properties` did the trick for me:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=<gmail_id>
spring.mail.password=<gmail_password>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Note that if you have enabled 2-Step Verification for your Gmail account then the `gmail_password` in the above configuration should not be an ordinary password but a 16-character application password generated for your Google account. Follow this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) to see the details and to generate your Google App Password.

Comment: spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust - that saved me! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main answer:

`props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");`

only worked after I removed the following:

```
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

If your context is android application , 
then make sure your android device time is set to current date and time. 
The underlying exception is 
"The SSL certificates was not getting authenticated."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works for me on localhost:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

The error is only thrown on localhost, so you should try on remote servers too. Usually, it is the snippet of code mentioned above that works well without `ssl.trust` property

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution bro. It's guaranteed

1) First of all open your gmail account from which you wanted to send mail, like in you case ""xyz@gmail.com"

2) open this link below https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

3) click on "Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account." option

4) Then turn on it

5) that's it (:

here is my code

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SendEmail {

   final String senderEmailID = "Sender Email id";
final String senderPassword = "Sender Pass word";
final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com";
final String emailServerPort = "465";
String receiverEmailID = null;
static String emailSubject = "Test Mail";
static String emailBody = ":)";
public SendEmail(String receiverEmailID, String emailSubject, String emailBody)
{
this.receiverEmailID=receiverEmailID;
this.emailSubject=emailSubject;
this.emailBody=emailBody;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.user",senderEmailID);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
try
{
Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setText(emailBody);
msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmailID));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
new InternetAddress(receiverEmailID));
Transport.send(msg);
System.out.println("Message send Successfully:)");
}
catch (Exception mex)
{
mex.printStackTrace();
}
}
public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmailID, senderPassword);
}
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SendEmail mailSender;
        mailSender = new SendEmail("Receiver Email id","Testing Code 2 example","Testing Code Body yess");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your JavaMail lib (mail.jar or javax.mail.jar). Maybe you need a newer one.
Download the newest version from here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/

Comment: Latest version has moved to the Eclipse Foundation: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.mail

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using **OpenJDK**, when I **switched** to **OracleJDK** the issue was resolved.

Comment: I don't think that's a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the smtpsend program that comes with JavaMail, as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  If that fails in the same way, there's something wrong with your JDK configuration or your network configuration.

Comment: It Still did not, How would I know if there's a problem with my JDK configuration or network configuration?

Comment: What still did not what?  If smtpsend fails in the same way, that's how you know the problem isn't with your code but with something else, most likely your JDK configuration or network configuration.  If you have a firewall or antivirus running on your machine, try disabling while you run the test.  What version of the JDK are you using?  Try reinstalling the JDK to see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

What helped me fix this, and i have tried everything before this, was to configure my installed jre to JRE 1.8.

Steps in Eclipse:  Windows>preferences>java>installed JRE>jre1.8.0

If it is set to jdk, switch to jre(which is what is supposed to be set to by default with the latest java version).