# can not change TLS protocol version on java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tls1.2

I wrote a simple app to send email to our smtp server. Java version is 1.8.0_101
Our server use only TLSv1.2. I wrote a simple app to send email to our server. I build this soft as jar and run it. It works normally and java use default tls version which is 1.2 on jdk1.8. Then I wrote a web service that accept request and send email to out smtp server. I use tomcat v9.0(also tested v7 and v8) I build war file and put the tomcat web app folder. But when I call my web service I got the below error

> Could not convert socket to TLS.
>   Remote host closed connection during handshake

Then I realized that java does not use TLSv1.2 and use TLSv1. I tried lots of solution but no ones helped me. I could not change TLS version. Is there any way to change TLS version? Do I change this config on java side or tomcat?

Comment: does your webapp use Javamail to send Mail? What do you see in the Stack Trace?

Comment: yes. i used it.

Comment: answers here might help then, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115453/javamail-could-not-convert-socket-to-tls-gmail

Comment: thanks but not. but not related my problem.